# MySQL update not using indexes with WHERE IN clause after certain value

Tags: mysql

We have a table having around 10 million records and we are trying to update some columns using the id(primary key) in the where clause.

```
UPDATE  table_name SET column1=1, column2=0,column3='2022-10-30' WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,......etc);
```

Scenario 1: when there are 3000 or fewer ids in the IN clause and if I try for EXPLAIN, then the 'possible_keys' and 'key' show the PRIMARY, and the query gets executed very fast.

Scenario 2: when there are 3000 or more ids(up to 30K) in the IN clause and if I try for EXPLAIN, then the 'possible_keys' shows NULL and the 'key' shows the PRIMARY and the query runs forever. If I use FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) then the 'possible_keys' and the 'key' shows the PRIMARY and the query gets executed very fast.

Scenario 3: when there are more than 30k ids in the IN clause and even if I use FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY), the 'possible_keys' shows NULL, and the 'key' shows the PRIMARY and the query runs forever.

I believe the optimizer is going for a full table scan instead of an index scan. Can we make any change such that the optimizer goes for an index scan instead of a table scan? Please suggest if there are any parameter changes required to overcome this issue.

The MySQL version is 5.7

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to just provide an ad-hoc table with all the ids and join table_name from it:

```
update (select 1 id union select 2 union select 3) ids
join table_name using (id) set column1=1, column2=0, column3='2022-10-30';
```

In mysql 8 you can use a values table constructor which is a little more terse (omit "row" for mariadb, e.g. `values (1),(2),(3)`):

```
update (select null id where 0 union all values row(1),row(2),row(3)) ids
join table_name using (id) set column1=1, column2=0, column3='2022-10-30';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mmCAd_GJ)

Comment: Thanks, @ysth
But I'm trying to understand why it's behaving in this way and also want to know if we can make any changes so that the optimizer goes for an index scan instead of a full table scan.

Comment: you are not the only one to run into this (in with a long value list, possibly in proportion to table rows, opting for a full scan).  IIRC some people have hit it after upgrading to 5.7.  I thought I'd seen mention of a setting that would affect it once, but I searched pretty thoroughly and couldn't find such a thing.  I don't remember if this is also an issue on 8.  IMO it is a bug that FORCE INDEX isn't fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

When `UPDATEing` a significant chunk of a table wit all the same update values, I see a red flag.

Do you always update the same set of rows?  Could that info be in a smaller separate table that you JOIN to?

Or may some other *structural* schema change that focuses on helping the Updates be faster?

If you must have a long IN list, I suggest doing 100 at a time.  And don't try to `COMMIT` all 3000+ in the same transaction.  (Committing in chunks mak violate some business logic, so you may not want to do such.)